# Div not resizing when document is ready (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code. It works fine on Firefox.

```
var imageGrad = $('.cuadro-azul-consejo'),
    image = $('.img.foto');

function resizeDiv () {
    imageGrad.height(image.height());
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img.foto").each(function() {
            $('.cuadro-azul-consejo').css("height",$(this).innerHeight());
            $('.cuadro-azul-consejo .outter-azul').css("height",$(this).innerHeight());
        });
    })
}

resizeDiv();
$(window).resize(function() { resizeDiv(); });
```

The code takes the height from the image and applies on the div, but when the page loads, the div takes `0px` height. I have to resize the window to make it work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing `image = $('.img.foto');` to `image = $('img.foto');`

Comment: I believe mistake is you have this in your header. So when the code executes there is nothing loaded yet and there for doesn't take effect. Try putting this in the footer of your website and try again!

Comment: You try load the images first, if exist images call the function resize

Answer (score 3):

your `$(document).ready(function()` is inside the function, create the function and call it on document ready and window resize